# Let $\mathbf x_n=(\cos n,\sin n).$ Prove the sequence has a subsequence which converges to a point on the unit circle.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $\mathbf x_n=(\cos n,\sin n).$ Prove the sequence has a subsequence which converges to a point on the unit circle.(Use sequential continuity.)
>
> Sequential continuity: If $f(\mathbf x)$ is continuous at $\mathbf a$, and defined for all $\mathbf x_n$, then $$\mathbf x_n \to \mathbf a \Rightarrow f(\mathbf x_n) \to f(\mathbf a).$$

Comment: what do you know about compactness? or the theorem of Bolzano-Weierstrass?

Comment: @VanillaThunder Do you mean the unit circle is a compact set, then use Bolzano-Weierstrass? But I have not learned the compactness of the unit circle.

Comment: yeah, then just follow the good answer from copper.hat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\|x_n\| =1$ , so if a subsequence converges to $x$ then $\|x\| =1$ since $\| \cdot\|$ is continuous.

Since $\cos n \in [-1,1]$ for all $n$ and $[-1,1]$ is compact, we see that some subsequence converges to some point $c \in [-1,1]$. That is, $\cos n_k \to c$ for some subsequence $(n_1,n_2,...)$.

Now repeat for $\sin n_k \in [-1,1]$. There is a subsequence of the subsequence and a point $s \in [-1,1]$ such that $\sin n_{k_i} \to s$.

Since $\|x_{n_{k_i}} \| = 1$ for all $i$, and $x_{n_{k_i}} \to (c,s)$, we see that $\|(c,s)\| = 1$, which lies on the unit circle.

Comment: Copperhat.Wonderful! You use that 1) Every bounded sequence of reals has a convergent subsequence, since compact , the limit of the subsequence is in [-1,1].Ok? ++

Comment: That is correct Peter.

Comment: Copperhat.Have to say it again : A wonderful answer.Chapeau!++

Comment: @PeterSzilas: You are overly generous, but your comment has lightened my day :-).

Answer (score 0):

A proof which uses sequential compactness idea. Suppose that $(x_n)$ has no convergent subsequence. Then for every $y\in \mathbb{S}^1:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2:|x|=1\}$ there is an open neighborhood $N(y)$ that contains only finitely many terms from $(x_n)$. The collection $\{N(y)\}_{y\in\mathbb{S}^1}$ is an open cover for $\mathbb{S}^1$. But $\mathbb{S}^1$ set is a compact set (since it is a bounded and closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$). Hence there is a finite subcover $\{N(y_i)\}_{i\in I}$ where $I$ is a finite index set such that $\mathbb{S}^1\subseteq\bigcup_{i\in I}N(y_i)$. But this would imply that $(x_n)$ has only finitely many terms. This is impossible since the sequence $(x_n)$ has infinitely many terms.